# My ps3 controller stopped working 2 days ago

Tags: usb, input-devices, ps3

I used to use my ps3 controller to play games, and a couple of days ago it stopped working.  I get this message during boot up (after BIOS):

```
[ (some numers)] sony 0003.054c.(more numbers): can't set operational mode
```

qtsixa still recognizes the controller being plugged in. My best guess is there was an update to a dependent or repository or something.

I also tried to connect a different ps3 controller with a different cord in a different USB slot - no change. I have also tried resetting them both with the little button on the back.

I entered `lsusb` in terminal and in usb port 7 it says:

```
Sony Corp. Batoh Device / PlayStation 3 Controller
```

Jstest & antimicro don't recognize that the controller is there.

Comment: I am having this problem too, if you are on 14.04 it is the kernel update from a couple days ago that caused this. Booting in to the older kernel makes it work for me, but I can't figure out how to get it working in the new one. I've tried reinstalling sixad and its dependencies.

Comment: AHHH I'm so glad I'm not the only one!  I barely know what a kernal is, much less how to switch them.  To fix it I re installed 14.04, and I'm not updating.  We need someone who knows better.  Meybe there's a correlation!  What system are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Hu guys, the problem is a bug in Linux kernel:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1326725

Please add more info or subscribe to that bug to be acknowledged of any progress.